# Is it possible to set up Pypandoc to convert the file using the same paper size, alignment, table, color, etc from the native Word file?

Tags: python-3.x, xcode, macos, pdflatex, pypandoc

I have recently installed MacLatex to be able to use the pypandoc in python to convert docx in pdf, but finally it works fine, the problem is the file came in PDF messed up all the alignment, fonts, paper size different from the original file.

Is it possible to change something in pypandoc or pdflatext configuration to fix it up?

My code is simple:

```
result = pypandoc.convert_file(
'/Users/user/Desktop/Neto/Python/Word Converter to PDF/T20491c Conditions of Tendering Protected.docx', 'pdf', outputfile='/Users/user/Desktop/Neto/Python/Word Converter to PDF/new.pdf')
```

print(result)

Thanks